# Hide extra menus from Wordpress Dashboard

Tags: plugins, wp-admin

How can hide extra menus from Wordpress dashboard. That is some plugins gives plugin settings menu may under Settings or anywhere else, how we can hide all this type of extra menus while plugin active

Answer (score 2):

## Update

As the Answer wasn't best practice, I replace it with a link to my simple plugin that even does more than the OP needed. You can take it as reference on how to (re)move different things in the admin UI.

It's freely available Open Source Software. I encourage you to fork it.

#### Functionality

The Plugin removes:

- All Dashboard Widgets except for “Incoming Links”
- All built in taxonomies and leaves only the “nav-menu” taxonomy
- The built in post type “Post”
- Changes the option “show on front” to “pages”
- Changes the initial posts query to search for the page with the lowest ID
- All admin bar items and leaves only the site name that can be used to access the public view
- Admin Menu items and submenu items: Posts, Links, Comments
- The admin menu items for Plugin & Theme Editor
- All Settings admin menu items and replaces them with the “All Settings” Page and makes it only accessible for ‘manage_options’ capability
- Removes the “capitalPdangit” filter from content, title and comment text, in case you add those filter in CPT related stuff

[**Detailed Description & Download**](http://unserkaiser.com/plugins/wp-strip-naked/)

#### WP Strip Naked

[image]

Comment: An easy way to find out the names is just to `print_r($wp_meta_boxes);` so you an see what to unset.

Answer (score 1):

Check this [Adminimize plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/adminimize/) with the help of this plugin you can customize the wordpress admin area.

Answer (score 0):

admin menu editor plugin never fails me http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/admin-menu-editor/

Comment: Lone link is considered a poor answer (see [FAQ#deletion]) since it is meaningless by itself and target resource is not guaranteed to be alive in the future. Please try to include at least summary of information you are linking to.

Comment: the other answers are just the same one-liner